# Passing and returning a struct from a function

Tags: c

I have a function with a book struct array, but when i try to return it to my main it does not return the values and store them in the array. If the addBook function has to be void how would i work around that so that i can access the array elements later.

```
void addBook(struct Book book[], int *size) {

    if (*size == MAX_BOOKS) {
        printf("The inventory is full\n");

    }
    else {

        printf("ISBN:");
        scanf("%d", &book[*size]._isbn);
        printf("Title:");
        scanf("%s", book[*size]._title);
        getchar();
        printf("Year:");
        scanf("%d", &book[*size]._year);
        printf("Price:");
        scanf("%f", &book[*size]._price);
        printf("Quantity:");
        scanf("%d", &book[*size]._qty);
        *size++;
        printf("The book is successfully added to the inventory.\n");
    }
    return book;
}

int main(void) {

    struct Book book[MAX_BOOKS];
    int size = 0;
    int i;
    int option;


    printf("Welcome to the Book Store\n");
    printf("=========================\n");

    do {
        menu();
        printf("Select: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option) {

        case 0:
            printf("Goodbye!\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            displayInventory(book, size);
            break;
        case 2:
            addBook(book, &size);
            break;
        case 3:
            //checkPrice();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid input, try again:\n");
        }
    } while (option != 0);
}
```

Comment: 1) A pointer is not the object it points to! 2) Your function is `void`, it does not return anything. Format the code properly! If you get a warning you have too little text for too much code, that should tell you something! Don't work around it by not formatting your code..

Comment: Your sarcasm isn't fixing the code either! To answer your question, you can access the element last inserted by accessing `books[size-1]`

Comment: @Olaf 1) I am adopting your style of speaking in points 2) I am starting right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement isn't going to do what you're intending as the `addBook`'s function signature says it returns void. I'm surprised that the code as is actually compiled without an error about this.

Anyways, the book data can be returned from the same way it was passed in - as an input and output parameter.

Essentially your code could look like the following (which is only meant to be an example of code that compiles and works to save info entered in from standard input into the book):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Book {
    int value;
};

#define MAX_BOOKS 2

void addBook(struct Book book[], int *size) {
    if (*size == MAX_BOOKS) {
        printf("The inventory is full\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Value:");
        scanf("%d", &book[*size].value);
        (*size)++;
        printf("The book is successfully added to the inventory.\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct Book book[MAX_BOOKS];
    int size = 0;

    addBook(book, &size);
    printf("Book 1: Value=%d\n", book[0].value);
}
```

And here's how this looks when run:

```
$ ./main
Value:9
The book is successfully added to the inventory.
Book 1: Value=9
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the line `*size++;`. You should use parenthesis, otherwise you are modifying the pointer to size, not the value. It should be `(*size)++`.
Also, the addBook function should not return anything, since it is void, and it is changing the content of the array book already.